# Filling 2D array with blocks

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I am looking for ideas of how to write an algorithm that is going to populate 2d array with predefined set of blocks/arrays.

Let's say you have 2d array 5x5 (so 25 fields), and have 6 elements you want to randomly fit into it (accordingly 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3 piece straight blocks). What is important - I want to put those randomly either horizontally or vertically, but no cell can be left with nothing.

The end effect should look like this (given the blocks of X elements on the left side)

[image]

This is somewhat related to packaging algorithms, although here the idea is that I specify the container dimensions (2d array) let's say 8x4, and randomize X amount of stripes length 3-5 that will be fit into array. The sum of all lengths of stripes will be equal to array size (so no cell is left empty).

On top of that, I think, I could add a fail-safe feature, meaning that after putting most stripes into Array and last one cant fit, algorithm could find any empty cells and fill it with neighbouring element so that the stripes are longer, but not longer than 5 elements

Comment: how does a 5, 4, or 3 piece block look like? Maybe you can give an example or an image in the best case.

Comment: @SaiBot hey! I've attached an image, basically those are straight elements (like I-block in Tetris)

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Have you looked at [packing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems), specifically [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu)? In general the problem seems to be hard, but for your  special case there might be a solution.

Comment: @SaiBot I've edited my question, it's somewhat related but here I am not trying to make the array as small as possible, but rather fill it with elements I create basing on array size (so the only input is array width & height). Added also idea what to do when empty cell is left

Comment: Are your arrays always smallish and do you have to do this quickly or do you have a little time?

Comment: @Richard My arrays will be at most 12x12 so 144 cells (but that's with some safe margin, I expect most of them be smaller than 10x10), and I do have plenty of time, it's going to be run once, can do even overnight ;)

Comment: Maybe a backtracking approach ? try placing blocks in each location, if you are out of blocks, everything fits and you are done else backtrack?

Comment: Also see [Bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). *objects of different volumes must be packed into a finite number of bins or containers each of volume V in a way that minimizes the number of bins used.* In this case, you run the algorithm with bins of your nxn size. If the result is anything other than 1 bin, it can't be done.